# Scraping email address from within a script using regex in python with bs4

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find

I'm trying to scrape the email address from a website where the email is nested within a script, and a simple "find/findAll + .text" isn't doing the trick.

source html:

`<script>EMLink('com','aol','mikemhnam','<div class="emailgraphic"><img style="position: relative; top: 3px;" src="https://www.naylornetwork.com/EMailProtector/text-gif.aspx?sx=com&nx=mikemhnam&dx=aol&size=9&color=034af3&underline=yes" border=0></div>','pcoc.officialbuyersguide.net Inquiry','onClick=\'$.get("TrackLinkClick", { LinkType: "Email", LinkValue: "mikemhnam@aol.com", MDSID: "CPC-1210", AdListingID: "" });\'')</script>
<br/>`

My current approach was to try a "findAll +" regex expression like so:

```
for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(email.findAll("([\w\._]+\@([\w_]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)"))
```

but in jupyter this is only returning a `[] :/`

Is there an issue with the regex expression or a simpler way to try to tease out the email here?

Answer (score 1):

Although regex may be more robust over time, in my experience these parts of scripts tags remain pretty constant so consider a plan B of using split

```
html ='''

<script>EMLink('com','aol','mikemhnam','<div class="emailgraphic"><img style="position: relative; top: 3px;" src="https://www.naylornetwork.com/EMailProtector/text-gif.aspx?sx=com&nx=mikemhnam&dx=aol&size=9&color=034af3&underline=yes" border=0></div>','pcoc.officialbuyersguide.net Inquiry','onClick=\'$.get("TrackLinkClick", { LinkType: "Email", LinkValue: "mikemhnam@aol.com", MDSID: "CPC-1210", AdListingID: "" });\'')</script>
<br/>

'''

print(html.split('LinkValue: "')[1].split('"')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you aren't using the right `findall` method. You need to `import re` and then use the [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method, not the `findAll()` method (note the case difference of the letter "A"). The function's interface is:

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

For details, see [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) of the `re` doc on finding all adverbs.

Comment: Thanks! I revised the code to this:

`for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(re.findall(r"([\w\._]+\@([\w_]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)"),text)`

but am now getting this error: TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Is the 'string' different from 'text'?

Comment: You need to revise your new code to be `print(re.findall(r"([\w\._]+\@([\w_]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)", text))`

Comment: Hmm :/ now getting a different error:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: For reference, the full code I'm using within this html block: `for company_name in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(company_name.find('h1').text)
    
for phone in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(phone.find(class_='Disappear').text)
    
for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
    print(re.findall(r"([\w\._]+\@([\w_]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)",text))`

Do I need to tear it down and build from scratch using re rather than bs4?

Comment: In the last line, try replacing `text` with `soup`.

Comment: The full error text:
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0dc727578b6e> in <module>
      7 for email in soup.findAll(class_='ListingPageNameAddress NONE'):
----> 8     print(re.findall(r"([\w\._]+\@([\w_]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]+)",soup))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    221 
    222     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 223     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    224 
    225 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Got me stumped. Basically, the field where I recommended `text` is supposed to be the text on which you try to match the regex.

Comment: Thanks for the help to this point! Will try to dig through some posts related to that specific error to see what the issue might be